# Animate each text lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, delay

```
$("span").click(function(){
$("div").fadeToggle();
});

$("span").click( function(){
    $("a").css({ opacity: '0' });
    $(".text1").delay(200).animate({ opacity: '1' });
    $(".text2").delay(400).animate({ opacity: '1' });
    $(".text3").delay(600).animate({ opacity: '1' });
});
```

I want to animate my text in the following way:

When you click on the "CLICK HERE" text, the links in the pink div should animate. Each line should fade in, one after the other.

However, I think my code is wrong, because if you click the "CLICK HERE" text several times in quick succession, animation build up occurs.

How should I fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/XdLzp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop the animation queue on the items e.g.

```
<a class="content-toggle" href="#">CLICK HERE</a>

<div class="content">
    <div>TEXT 1</div>
    <div>TEXT 2</div>
    <div>TEXT 3</div>
</div>

$('.content-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var content = $('.content');

    // Stop any ongoing animations and hide children.
    content.finish().children().finish().hide();

    content.fadeToggle(400, 'swing', function() {
        animateChildrenIn(content);
    });
});

function animateChildrenIn(parent) {
    parent.children().each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay((i + 1) * 200).fadeIn(800); 
    });
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4RW5d/

Comment: Almost perfect !
The problem is that I need a SPAN between the "links".
Now, it doesn't work : http://jsfiddle.net/4RW5d/1/
And I really need this span ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try somthing like this

```
$("span").click(function(){
$("div").fadeToggle();
});

$("span").click( function(){
    $("a").css({ opacity: '0' });
    $(".text1").animate({ opacity: '1' },function(){
        $(".text2").animate({ opacity: '1' },function(){
            $(".text3").animate({ opacity: '1' });
        });
    });


});
```